# Limit output framerate to maximum 30

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I have a bunch of videos in a folder to convert. The videos come in a variety of container formats - mp4, mkv, avi, mpg, etc. All I would do is to drag videos into this folder and I run a script to read each file in the folder and execute ffmpeg to convert each video to a specific setting.

What I want to do is to set the output framerate of each video to the following logic:

- if the input framerate is 30 fps or less, keep the output framerate to the input file framerate, eg. if the input framerate is 24 fps.
- if the input framerate is more than 30, set the output framerate to 30 fps, eg. if the input framerate is 60 fps.

eg. something like: `if=input<=30fps -r input_framerate else=input>30fps -r 30`

I have read the documentation and more than two hours of Googling, but did not find a suitable command to do this.

Please enlighten.

Comment: @Gyan Your [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334291/ffmpeg-reduce-fps-if-over-threshold-but-do-not-increase-if-under-threshold) didn't solve my question. Using this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t86sKsR4pnk), ffprobe prints out `Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 454 kb/s, 20.49 fps, 59.94 tbr, 19001 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)`

Comment: @Gyan Here is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297824/ffmpeg-cli-set-r-30-if-input-30-fps-else-r-to-take-input-fps-if-30-fps