# ffmpeg CLI set -r 30 if input => 30 fps, else -r to take input fps if < 30 fps

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, frame-rate, rate

I posted my [original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59261211/limit-output-framerate-to-maximum-30). Tried [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334291/ffmpeg-reduce-fps-if-over-threshold-but-do-not-increase-if-under-threshold). But it does not solve my question.

Here's what I did. Download [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t86sKsR4pnk) from Youtube as a test. Using ffprobe gives:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 1k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
```

The ffmpeg command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i Iron_Man_1080p_60fps.mp4 -vf "select='eq(n,0)+if(gt(t-prev_selected_t,1/30.01),1,0)'" -vsync 0 -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 64k Iron_Man_1080p_60fps_CONVERTED.mp4
```

ffprobe my output file `Iron_Man_1080p_60fps_CONVERTED.mp4`:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 454 kb/s, 20.49 fps, 59.94 tbr, 19001 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
```

As you can see, the fps dropped from 59.94 fps to 20.49 fps.

I'm not sure why the suggested solution does not work.

```
ffmpeg -i 120.mp4 -vf "select='eq(n,0)+if(gt(t-prev_selected_t,1/30.01),1,0)'" -vsync 0 out.mp4
```

Perhaps -vf does not set a fixed framerate?

Could someone provide an alternative solution using the -r flag please?

Here's re-stating question:

- Set -r 30 if input fps => 30 fps
- Set -r input_fps if input fps < 30 fps

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The time_base for the sample video is coarse, so the video is actually VFR. Change the interval to `1/30.5` to keep frames which are just beyond the threshold for `1/30.01`

```
-vf "select='eq(n,0)+if(gt(t-prev_selected_t,1/30.50),1,0)'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much again @Gyan! This works like a charm! For those who are thinking of converting both framerate and scaling, eg. scaling down a 2160p 60fps video to 1080p 30fps, you can simply use: `-vf "select='eq(n,0)+if(gt(t-prev_selected_t,1/30.50),1,0)'",scaling=-1:1080`

Comment: My video is `Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540 [SAR 4096:4095 DAR 65536:36855], 188 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)` when I use `ffmpeg.exe -i 123456.mp4 -vf "select='eq(n,0)+if(gt(t-prev_selected_t,1/20.50),1,0)'" -vsync 0 ooo.mp4` or ` ffmpeg.exe -i 123456.mp4 -vf "select='eq(n,0)+if(gt(t-prev_selected_t,1/20.01),1,0)'" -vsync 0 ooo.mp4` to reset the frame below 20,

Comment: it always get `Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540 [SAR 4096:4095 DAR 65536:36855], 166 kb/s, 12.50 fps, 12.50 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)` which is 12.5 not 20fps.

Comment: Yes, it will divide the framerate by an integer divisor.

Comment: When I do this with a 120fps video and output it as HLS, the .ts segments are still reporting as 120fps in Windows file detail view, and the .m3u8 segment lengths are listed incorrectly at 1/4 the actual segment durations. Any ideas @Gyan?